# adding item during iteration in java special usecase

Tags: java, list, date, iterator, listiterator

I've got a function that should return a list of dates (`java.sql.Date`) based within a range set as `startDate` - `endDate`. I first added the `startDate` and want to increment it (either +1 day, week or month), and then keep going from the "newest" date until reaching the endDate.

I've tried using a traditional foreach which does not work as it doesn't allow adding new dates while iterating, so I switched to `ListIterator`.
This only goes into `while` once, increments the date, adds it but then apparently doesn't have a `next` because the `add` function doesn't append the item at the end(?)

What would be a practical way to solve this task?

```
public List<Date> getBookingDatesInRange(Date startDate, Date endDate, boolean isDaily, boolean isWeekly) {

    List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    dates.add(startDate);
    ListIterator<Date> iter = dates.listIterator();         
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        LocalDate new = iter.next().toLocalDate();
        Date newDate;
        if(isDaily) {
            newDate= Date.valueOf(new.plusDays(1));
        } else if(isWeekly) {
            newDate= Date.valueOf(new.plusWeeks(1));
        } else {
            newDate= Date.valueOf(new.plusMonths(1));
        }
        if(newDate.before(endDate) || newDate.equals(endDate) {
            iter.add(newDate);
        } else {
            return dates;
    }                   
}
```

Comment: New element is inserted _before_ old one, see docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29

Comment: You probably don’t want to use `java.sql.Date`, in particular not when you can use `LocalDate`. With a modern JDBC driver or a modern JPA implementation (like Hibernate) you can store `LocalDate` into your SQL database or use it in queries. Only if you need a `Date` for a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade just now, you do need one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to do the while loop based on an Iterator? Would it not be more logical to base it on just the date check you do during the iteration?

```
  public static List<Date> getBookingDatesInRange(Date startDate, Date endDate, boolean isDaily, boolean isWeekly) {

  List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
  dates.add(startDate);
  Date newDate = startDate;
  while(newDate.before(endDate) || newDate.equals(endDate)) {

    if(isDaily) {
       newDate = Date.valueOf(newDate.toLocalDate().plusDays(1));
    } else if(isWeekly) {
         newDate = Date.valueOf(newDate.toLocalDate().plusWeeks(1));
    } else {
      newDate = Date.valueOf(newDate.toLocalDate().plusMonths(1));
    }
    dates.add(newDate);
    }
  }
  return dates;
}
```

Comment: Way easier approach that I wasn't able to think of, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `ListIterator::nextIndex()` when adding a new item, and then reset the iterator variable to `ArrayList::listIterator(int index)`.